# Dynamically "pivot" rows into columns - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, dynamic-pivot

I have a table that looks like this:

```
DtCreated               | UserName | Question    | Answer
2016-09-24 14:30:11.927 | mauricio | Senha       | 99658202
2016-09-24 14:30:11.927 | mauricio | Inteiro     | 10
2016-09-24 14:30:11.927 | mauricio | Telefone    | (915) 438-05
2016-09-24 14:30:11.927 | mauricio | Email       | mauriiciobarbosa@gmail.com
2016-09-24 14:30:11.927 | mauricio | Texto Livre | nksnksjksj nsjsnsjjs
2016-09-24 14:30:11.927 | mauricio | Decimal     | 0.9
```

How can I use pivot to transform this data into this?

```
DtCreated               | UserName | Senha    | Inteiro | Telefone     | Email                      | Texto Livre          | Decimal
2016-09-24 14:30:11.927 | mauricio | 99658202 |  10     | (915) 438-05 | mauriiciobarbosa@gmail.com | nksnksjksj nsjsnsjjs | 0.9
```

PS: "Question" column has dynamically created values and data should be grouped by "DtCreated" and "Username" fields.

This is the SQL code i'm using right now:

```
SELECT 

sf.[DtCreated],    
sf.[UserName],
fc.Title as Question,
sv.Value as Answer

  FROM [form].[SubmissionForm] sf
  inner join [form].[Submission] s on
  sf.id = s.SubmissionForm_Id
  inner join [form].[FormComponent] fc on s.FormComponentId = fc.Id
  inner join [form].[SubmissionValue] sv on s.Id = sv.Submission_Id
  where sf.Id = '0DBA8590-C33E-48F8-9E64-C68EEFC536FF'
  order by sf.[DtCreated]
```

I've found some dynamic pivot examples but could not fit them into my specific case.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Prdp, I'm almost there. This is the dynamic pivot code 'til now:

```
DECLARE @sql      VARCHAR(max)='', 
        @col_list VARCHAR(8000)='' 

SET @col_list = (SELECT DISTINCT Quotename(fc.Title) + ',' 
                 FROM   [form].[SubmissionForm] sf
  inner join [form].[Submission] s on
  sf.id = s.SubmissionForm_Id
  inner join [form].[FormComponent] fc on s.FormComponentId = fc.Id
  inner join [form].[SubmissionValue] sv on s.Id = sv.Submission_Id
                 FOR xml path('')) 

SET @col_list = LEFT (@col_list, Len(@col_list) - 1) 

SET @sql = 'select [DtCreated],[UserName]' + @col_list 
           + ' from (SELECT 

sf.[DtCreated],    
sf.[UserName],
fc.Title,
sv.Value

  FROM [form].[SubmissionForm] sf
  inner join [form].[Submission] s on
  sf.id = s.SubmissionForm_Id
  inner join [form].[FormComponent] fc on s.FormComponentId = fc.Id
  inner join [form].[SubmissionValue] sv on s.Id = sv.Submission_Id
) pivot (max([sv.Value]) for [fc.Title] in (' 
           + @col_list + '))pv' 

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Please remove picture and add sample data in text format

Comment: You can use a dynamic pivot or a dynamic cross tab for this sort of thing. This has been answered thousands of times on SO and other places around the internet.

Comment: I'm having trouble to transform this sql code. Can  you show me some sample code, please? Thanks.

Comment: Save the result of your query to temp table and apply one of the dynamic pivot solutions already posted on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `Dynamic Pivot`

```
DECLARE @sql      VARCHAR(max)='', 
        @col_list VARCHAR(8000)='' 

SET @col_list = (SELECT DISTINCT Quotename([question]) + ',' 
                 FROM   Yourquery
                 FOR xml path('')) 

SET @col_list = LEFT (@col_list, Len(@col_list) - 1) 

SET @sql = 'select [DtCreated],[UserName]' + @col_list 
           + ' from Yourquery pivot (max([Answer]) for [Question] in (' 
           + @col_list + '))pv' 

EXEC(@sql)
```

**Update :** You are missing `Alias` name to the `sub-select`

```
SET @sql = 'select [DtCreated],[UserName]' + @col_list 
           + ' from (SELECT 

sf.[DtCreated],    
sf.[UserName],
fc.Title,
sv.Value

  FROM [form].[SubmissionForm] sf
  inner join [form].[Submission] s on
  sf.id = s.SubmissionForm_Id
  inner join [form].[FormComponent] fc on s.FormComponentId = fc.Id
  inner join [form].[SubmissionValue] sv on s.Id = sv.Submission_Id
) a --here
pivot (max([sv.Value]) for [fc.Title] in (' 
           + @col_list + '))pv' 

EXEC(@sql)
```

**DEMO :**

*Schema setup*

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([DtCreated] datetime, [UserName] varchar(8), [Question] varchar(11), [Answer] varchar(26))
;


INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([DtCreated], [UserName], [Question], [Answer])
VALUES
    ('2016-09-24 14:30:11', 'mauricio', 'Senha', '99658202'),
    ('2016-09-24 14:30:11', 'mauricio', 'Inteiro', '10'),
    ('2016-09-24 14:30:11', 'mauricio', 'Telefone', '(915) 438-05'),
    ('2016-09-24 14:30:11', 'mauricio', 'Email', 'mauriiciobarbosa@gmail.com'),
    ('2016-09-24 14:30:11', 'mauricio', 'Texto Livre', 'nksnksjksj nsjsnsjjs'),
    ('2016-09-24 14:30:11', 'mauricio', 'Decimal', '0.9')
;
```

**Query :**

```
declare @sql varchar(max)='',@col_list varchar(8000)=''

set @col_list = (select distinct quotename([Question])+',' from #Table1
for xml path(''))

set @col_list = left (@col_list,len(@col_list)-1)

set @sql = 'select [DtCreated],[UserName]'+@col_list+' from
#Table1
pivot (max([Answer]) for [Question] in ('+@col_list+'))pv'

exec(@sql)
```

**Result :**

```
╔═════════════════════════╦══════════╦════════════════════════════╦═════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║        DtCreated        ║ Decimal  ║           Email            ║ Inteiro ║  Senha   ║   Telefone   ║     Texto Livre      ║
╠═════════════════════════╬══════════╬════════════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ 2016-09-24 14:30:11.000 ║ mauricio ║ mauriiciobarbosa@gmail.com ║      10 ║ 99658202 ║ (915) 438-05 ║ nksnksjksj nsjsnsjjs ║
╚═════════════════════════╩══════════╩════════════════════════════╩═════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

Comment: I've removed where clause and order by for testing purposes, This is what I got:
Mensagem 1038, Nível 15, Estado 4, Linha 1
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
Mensagem 156, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'pivot'.
Mensagem 1038, Nível 15, Estado 4, Linha 13

Comment: @thiago - post your dynamic query in question

Comment: Did not work: Mensagem 1038, Nível 15, Estado 4, Linha 1
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
Mensagem 102, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 13
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
Mensagem 1038, Nível 15, Estado 4, Linha 14
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] a....

Comment: @thiago - Are you sure the error message is generated from dynamic pivot query. I have added demo also for me it is working

Comment: I put my query into a temp table and process pivot from it. Now it's working fine! Thank you very much Prdp! You're the man!!