# Dynamic SQL Date Header

Tags: stored-procedures, sqlanywhere

I would like to ask a little help on using dynamic sql date header,
i have data that i count transaction group by date then by hours.
date range would be entered start date and end date.

my data is simple just date and time:

```
created_Date
'2020-01-14 13:25:20.147'
'2020-01-14 13:23:15.639'
'2020-01-14 12:27:48.896'
'2020-01-09 20:03:06.713'
'2020-01-09 19:33:05.032'
'2020-01-09 19:16:35.590'
'2020-01-09 19:08:19.788'
'2020-01-09 13:02:03.543'
'2020-01-09 12:23:12.595'
'2020-01-08 15:29:52.262'
'2020-01-08 15:17:31.247'
'2020-01-08 15:16:51.499'
'2020-01-08 13:29:47.661'
'2020-01-06 20:19:30.173'
```

currently found this code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "DBA"."test_trancountdaily"(@sdate datetime, @edate datetime)
BEGIN 
create table #trantable(TDate varchar(100),Hour varchar(2), count varchar(1000));
insert #trantable

SELECT CAST(created_date as date) AS ForDate,
       DATEPART(hour,created_date) AS OnHour,
       COUNT(*) AS Totals
FROM prescription
WHERE created_date >= @sdate and created_date <= @edate
GROUP BY CAST(created_date as date),
       DATEPART(hour,created_date)
ORDER BY CAST(created_date as date),
       DATEPART(hour,created_date) asc;
select * from #trantable;
END
```

my data are created_date datetime and would count how many transaction that is inside a Hour

but would like an output like this:

| HR | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-03 etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 2 |

thanks

bolivar1985

[image]

Comment: please include some sample data and the corresponding required result

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name currently im using sybase anywhere, and need to make this as stored procedure

Comment: This is something you wouldn't usually do in SQL, but in the GUI layer (your app or website that is running the query).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner just need a stored procedure for this, it will be called by powerbuilder datawindow to retrieved needed data in horizontal display, just as i posted.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of dynamic pivots on [so]; [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10404348/2029983), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39879697/2029983), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52761674/2029983). What were wrong with all these examples? What was your attempts and why didn't it work?

Comment: @Larnu problem is that in sybase, they don't have pivot which im trying to find if there is another way to do dynamic date header.

Comment: Use conditional aggregation, @ZumotakirukashiVergaraIII instead of `PIVOT` then; it's far less restrictive then. But you've taggged t-sql, so you have tagged that you are able to use `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 0):

[Sample Result in interactive sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6xjk.png)
Good Day,
Just solve query without using pivot in sybase it was mind troubling but got it.

set @sql_date = @sql_date + ', COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(prescription.created_date) = ''' + @ls_date +
''' AND #time_table.hrs = HOUR(prescription.created_date) THEN prescription.tran_id END) AS
[' + @ls_date + ']' ;

looping the date range to be given by user, and date as header.
bolivar1985